# Can I pass variables using EventEmitter from angular2 component?

Tags: angular

I am new to angular2 so please excuse if I use the wrong terms in describing my problem.

I have a simple component that lets a user choose an option. Now I want to dispatch this option to the parent component. I am doing this:

```
// import the necessary angular2 resources:
import {Component, Output, EventEmitter} from 'angular2/core';
...
// create the emitter in my component class:
export class MyClassThatLetsUserSelectSomeContentId{
   @Output() selectEvent: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
   public selectedId: string;
   // this does get called, showing the correct id in the console
   onSelect(selectedItem: MyCustomItem){
       this.selectedId = selectedItem.id;
       console.log("selectedId:" + this.selectedId);
       this.selectEvent.emit(this.selectedId);
   }
}
```

and in the main component I include it in the template like this:

```
<my-selector-component (selectEvent)="onItemSelected(selectedItemId)"></my-selector-component>
```

And the function does get calles, but the variable is undefined:

```
onItemSelected(selectedItemId: string){
    console.log("onItemSelected(" + selectedItemId + ")");
}
```

the console output is:

*log: onItemSelected(undefined)*

So what am I missing? **The event is sent and the function gets called but the parameter is lost**.

Maybe some other form of binding to the selected Id would be better altogether. I am open to any kind of solution as long as the parent component can react to a new select from the view component.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to use the `$event` variable to get the value you send when triggering the event:

```
<my-selector-component (selectEvent)="onItemSelected($event)">
</my-selector-component>
```

The value you provide as parameter of the `emit` method of the `EventEmitter` corresponds to it.

Comment: Thanks, this worked right away! was i simply too blind to see it in the docs or is this really hidden?

Comment: You're welcome! It's now so clear for events that custom components can trigger... No worries ;-)

Comment: Is it possible multiple parameters to the listener? e.g., `onItemSelected($event, more, more)`. I can make `$event` as an array, but just being curious.

Comment: @allenhwkim yes, you can pass. Typically, the $event is the 'native' object emitted by the event, for example mouse-enter event. While you can pass item object along in the second paramater